# Hash sign added to end of URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website, [stepaheadresidents.com](http://www.stepaheadresidents.com), and a hash sign (#) is automatically added to the end of the url. I would like to remove the hash tag. I know it's a JavaScript issue but I have no idea what the issue could be. I don't even know where to look in the source code. Could someone give me some pointers on where to look or what to look for?

Comment: That question is looking for a specific answer. I am just looking to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the script you're including from infusionsoft for the form in the sidebar:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ch115.infusionsoft.com/app/form/iframe/6285da82fa28847b2d8767f8623c185d"></script>
```

That script has code which adds the hash to the url executing every 30 milliseconds. There isn't anything you can do about it other than remove the widget, or contact them and ask them to change that behaviour.